Obtaining a holomorphic bundle structure on $E$ from $D'' \circ D'' = 0$
I'm trying to prove the following theorem:

Let $E$ be a $C^\infty$ complex vector bundle over a complex manifold $M$. If $D$ is a connection in $E$ such that $D'' \circ D'' = 0$, then there is a unique holomorphic vector bundle structure in $E$ such that $D'' = d''$.

The idea I had was to try and use $D$ to get an almost complex structure on $E$ and maybe use integrability and the Newlander-Nirenberg theorem, but I could not formulate a proof.
Is this a way to prove this or is there a simpler way to go about it?

Go back a step. On a complex manifold, how is $J$ related to the splitting $d=\partial+\bar\partial$? And isn’t integrability equivalent to $\bar\partial{}^2=0$?

$J$ gives meaning to the $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ forms? Also yes I think that integrability is equivalent to $\bar\partial{}^2=0$. @TedShifrin

Be more explicit. Can you recover $J$ from the splitting?
